# Bind @State picker value to a NSPredicate in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, core-data, combine

I have a view with a segmented picker. This view displays results of a FetchRequest.
I'd like the predicate linked to this request to change when the picker value change.

Here's what I tried but I can't get around the fact that @FetchRequest cannot use a @State var since they're not both created at init().

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
    SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)
], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", selectedTimeFrame.getDate() as NSDate)) var sessions: FetchedResults<Session>

@State private var selectedTimeFrame = TimeFrame.thisWeek
```

This give me this error which I understand but I can't think of another way to make this work:

> Cannot use instance member 'selectedTimeFrame' within property
> initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by setting an initial predicate for your FetchRequest, e.g.

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
    SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)
], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", TimeFrame.thisWeek as NSDate)) var sessions: FetchedResults<Session>

@State private var selectedTimeFrame = TimeFrame.thisWeek
```

and then in your view, update the predicate when the `State` changes, e.g.

```
.onChange(of: selectedTimeFrame) { selectedTimeFrame
    sessions.nsPreciate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", selectedTimeFrame.getDate() as NSDate)) 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately if the View containing this is re-init then the predicate using selectedTimeFrame is lost. A workaround is to set the predicate in body instead.